# Determine all numbers $x$ such that $\sin x = \sin a$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $a$ be a given number. Determine all numbers $x$ such that $\sin x = \sin a$.

You may suppose that $0 \le a \lt 2\pi$, and distinguish the cases $a = 
\frac\pi2$, $a = \frac{-\pi}2$ and $a \neq \frac{\pm\pi}2$

---

I know that I have to find a formula that gives me all numbers $x$ such that sin $x = \sin a$. Like $\sin \pi/6 = \sin 5\pi/6 = \sin 13\pi/6$ and so on. But I am having problem to find that.

Comment: Have you put any effort into finding a solution at all?

Comment: Yes. I know that I have to find a formula that gives me all numbers x such that sin x = sin a. Like sin pi/6 = sin 5pi/6 = sin 13pi/6 and so on. But I am having problem to find that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sin(\theta+2\pi k)=\sin \theta,k\in\Bbb{Z}$$
Also $$\sin(\theta)=\sin(\pi-\theta)$$

Comment: Ok. So I have $\sin a = \sin (a+2\pi * k)$ and $\sin a = \sin (\pi − a + 2\pi * k)$. But I am having problems to join them, so I would have just one function that gives me all numbers x that satisfy the equation $\sin x = \sin a$. Can you help me?

Comment: @LucasPG Why would you need 1 full equation?

Comment: Well, the exercise was asking to determine all numbers x. So I thought there would be a single equation that would give me all the numbers x. But if it is not possible to do that, then I think that is the answer the exercise wants. Do I need to do more than this, or is it just enough?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diagram below:[image: symmetries_of_sine_and_cosine]

Since reflection in the $y$-axis does not change the value of the sine function, $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$.  Since coterminal angles have the same sine, $\sin(\theta + 2k\pi) = \sin\theta$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Putting the two observations together yields $\sin(\pi - \theta + 2k\pi) = \sin\theta$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $\sin x = \sin a$, then 
\begin{align*}
x & = \begin{cases}
a + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\pi - a + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\end{cases}\\
& = \begin{cases}
a + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
-a + (2k + 1)\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\end{cases}\\
& = (-1)^na + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}